# OnTouchListener inside a method

Tags: android, listener, ontouchlistener

In my program i'm using this code:

```
  int value =100;

View.OnTouchListener button1listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        if (value==50) {
            System.out.println("button1, value 50");
        } else if (value==100) {
            System.out.println("button1, value 100");
        } else if (value==200) {
            System.out.println("button1, value 200");

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            System.out.println("No action");
    return false;   
}
};

button1.setOnTouchListener(button1listener);
```

It works fine but i want to make it for many buttons, so instead of copying and pasting i would like to have a method for it. I tried to do it on my own but my solution isn't correct and i'm not sure how can i make it. Code below presenting my wrong solution. So basically i would like to pack this piece of code into a method and then call it with setOnTouchListener and other parameters.

```
private void setListener(parameter1, String parameter2 ) {
int value =100;

View.OnTouchListener parameter1 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        if (value==50) {
            System.out.println(parameter2 + "value 50");
        } else if (value==100) {
            System.out.println(parameter2 + "value 100");
        } else if (value==200) {
            System.out.println(parameter2 + "value 200");

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            System.out.println("No action");
    return false;   
}
};
}
```

Comment: implements `OnTouchListener()` in your class and inside the method check the view that user clicked and do code if you want I can create na detailed answer.

Comment: You put `parameter1` in the parameter list without a type... So this won't compile. Plus, you  later redefined it

Comment: @BrunoFerreira i would like to see this

Comment: @AidanSalvatore the cricket_007 answer what I think just check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one interface like this

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnTouchListener {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) { // touched button 1
```

And when you find the button

```
findViewById(R.id.button1)
   .setOnTouchListener(YourActivity.this);
```